# When executing exe file: ImportError: matplotlib is required for plotting when the default backend "matplotlib" is selected when executing exe file

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyinstaller

I created an .exe file using pyinstaller. When I run it on Pycharm, it works perfectly.
But when I try to run the executable an error occurs.

Here's the full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DT_070621.py", line 397, in <module>
  File "DT_070621.py", line 315, in arquivos_saida
  File "pandas\plotting\_core.py", line 892, in __call__
  File "pandas\plotting\_core.py", line 1814, in _get_plot_backend
  File "pandas\plotting\_core.py", line 1754, in _load_backend
ImportError: matplotlib is required for plotting when the default backend "matplotlib" is selected.
[11304] Failed to execute script 'DT_070621' due to unhandled exception!
```

But when I check matplotlib version, everything seems fine.

```
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.__version__
'3.4.3'
```

I've also checked the backend being used:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> plt.get_backend()
'TkAgg'
```

I've also tried creating the .exe file like this:

```
pyinstaller --hidden-import=openpyxl --hidden-import=matplotlib --onefile DT_070621.py
```

But it didn't solve my problem.

I've also checked out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60977789/importerror-matplotlib-is-required-for-plotting-when-the-default-backend-matpl), but its description seems incomplete and there aren't answers that were useful in helping me solve this problem.

Here are the imports in my script:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.etree import ElementTree
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
```

What is going on and how do I solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError with Pyinstaller and Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33001327/7758804)

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `--hidden-import pandas.plotting._matplotlib` solved it.